# Can object instances persist between program executions?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a more philosophical question regarding the use of class objects in VBA.  I'd like to use class objects more but there are some apparent limitations.  I'd love it if the community could can find ways to overcome them.

Classes work well when you create and consume them in a single method or multiple methods which are all part of a sequence of code.  The problem lies in that if you want them to persist until the next time your code is triggered.  To keep them around you need to hold a reference to the object.  Typically this would be a global reference (if there are better ways to do this, I'd love to know).

The problem occurs when the project is reset and all objects are destroyed (or at least any public variable references).  There are a few ways that the VBA project can be reset.  We can ignore the ones that involve the user explicitly resetting it.  This leaves unhandled code errors.  It is possible to have a top level error handler in your own code as a catch all and prevent the error being displayed to the user.  However there is no way to handle errors in *other* people's code.  This would still result in a complete code reset destroying your class objects.

Any suggestions on how to overcome these issues?

Answer (score 0):

All 'status' information of the object are kept in `Object Properties`. As long as you are talking about your own class I assume that you talk about **limited number of `Object Properties`** you created. If so, you could try to catch each property change and write it somewhere- to `log sheet` or any kind of external file like txt or dat. For sure, it will be a time consuming for your code especially if you often change `Object Properties` values. However, if anything happened, which you could have not predicted, you will be able to read the last value of `Object Properties` from your log.

Moreover, you could try to keep `Object Properties` values in Windows System Registry but I have no idea how much it will influence efficiency of your program.

Comment: Not so much that but if you have an instance of an object and are holding its reference via a global reference (eg Public var As cSomeClass).  If the VBA project gets reset then the instance is nuked and there is no chance to run any code to do anything.  Moreover there is no way to run code immediately after it has been reset either.

Comment: In my idea you need to save property value each time you set property, not when the variable is terminated. That is the difference. And that is right- you need to figure out how to re-initialize your variable. But it states will be ready to use reading log file.

Comment: Reading and writing data to persistent storage is fine, I'm not so interested in the possibility of losing data.  More that the instances are destroyed.  For example, if your instances respond to events, then they cannot if the VBA project is reset which may screw up the functionality of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little sheepish on this one.  Since after more testing it seems that the VBA editor only resets the Active Project and all other projects remain intact!  So it would seem that most issues can be avoided by good error handling.  The user is still able to reset your program by hand but if they are willing to do that they are probably a savvy user and should expect errors to occur if they undertake this action.

I have some code I used to test this for reference:

```
Private ABoolValue As Boolean
Private AClass As Class1 ' Note this is just an empty class I added.


Public Sub Init()

    ABoolValue = True
    Set AClass = New Class1

End Sub


Public Sub TestValuesOfGlobals()

    ' Reset VBA.
    End

    ' Check that our variables are not initialised.
    Debug.Assert ABoolValue = False
    Debug.Assert AClass Is Nothing

    ' Reinitialise the variables.
    Init

    ' Check they are initialised.
    Debug.Assert ABoolValue = True
    Debug.Assert Not AClass Is Nothing

End Sub


Public Sub PrintValues()

    Debug.Print "The boolean variable is: " & CStr(ABoolValue)
    If AClass Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "The Class is Nothing"
    Else
        Debug.Print "The Class is NOT Nothing"
    End If

End Sub
```

Just paste into ThisWorkbook class of an Excel workbook and create a dummy Class module called Class1.  Run the Init method to instantiate the variables then navigate to a new VBA project and try to reset the VBA editor.  You can determine the values of the global variables by using the PrintValues method.

I posted this to our blog also: http://www.gravitycomputing.co.nz/resetting-vba-affects-active-project/